# How to calculate how much data is in ftp folders recursively

Tags: ftp

I would like to know how much data is in a remote folder (recursively) under ftp (from the command line). Wondering how to do that. Something like:

```
sizeof -r ftp://domain.com/foo/bar/*
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/), you can use:

```
echo "du -hs ." | lftp domain.com/foo/bar/ 2>&1
```

This will print the current directory's disk size including all subdirectories, in human-readable format (`-h`) and omitting output lines for subdirectories (`-s`). stderr output is rerouted to stdout with `2>&1` so that it is included in the output.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24845286/4468328)